# Hiding Winforms content on RDP client

Tags: c#, .net

I have a specific question about RDP and specifically about how a Winforms application reacts to screen sharing.

I have been searching wide and far for this, but have been unable to find anything at all. So I came to the conclusion I'm probably not looking for the right thing/name/concept.

So, I in a remote session with my father and he had a banking application open on his computer. But all I could see was a black window. No details at all. 
I restarted the session to make sure it wasn't a bug or anything. It wasn't. 
It was probably a security feature. I tried it on anyconnect and TeamViewer and got the same results.

So I'm guessing there is a way to tell the OS not to send any Screenshots of that particular application.

I would be very thankful if somebody could point me in the right direction, so I could research this. As of now, I'm completely lost. 
Is this possible? If so, does the windows API or mstsclib(??) support something like this?

Thank you very much for reading and sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: How do you know its a WinForm app and not a WPF app?

Comment: I'm not saying it is. But I would like to implement it in a Winform application. If this is only possible in WPF, I wouldn't mind switching to that.

Comment: Sounds like a security feature, i've heard of this before. Maybe they're hooking the screenshot functions like `BitBlt` etc. But i doubt there's anything you can do about it unless you write your own RDP software.

Comment: `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` is what i think those applications are using. Read https://yeasir007.blogspot.com/2019/10/how-to-prevent-disable-protect-screen-capture-of-windows-application.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I was able to do exactly what I want and more.

So, like Charles said, I used the `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` extern function to hide Winforms content.

My objective was to also apply this effect to unmanaged applications. 
Using the method on the Handler of the application window. 
So I just made a Form withe DisplayAffinity property set and, using `GetWindowLong` matched the Form location to that of the unmanaged applications window.